# Understanding this hypothesis testing exercise using P-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing

The exercise states that:

> Your team evaluates a new cannon ball and compares its distance
> performance to a new ball from your competitor. In an initial
> evaluation you test 10 of your new cannon balls and 10 of the
> competitor’s balls with the goal of determining if the average
> distance in yards travelled by your new ball is greater than the
> average distance travelled by the competitor’s ball. The resulting
> data is shown below. You might assume equal variances when using a
> statistical test. Which one of the following statements is correct?
>
> 1. The properly calculated P-value is in the range 0.15 < P <0.45. You have statistical evidence that your new ball travels farther on
>    average than the competition’s ball.
> 2. None of the statistical hypothesis tests discussed are appropriate
>    for the analysis of this data.
> 3. The properly calculated P-value is in the range 0.075 < P< 0.25. No evidence is found that your new ball travels farther on average
>    than the competition’s new ball.
> 4. A statistical hypothesis test cannot be applied in this case, because we have less than 12 data points for each type of ball.

| Competitor ball | My new ball |
| --- | --- |
| 341.0 | 314.2 |
| 308.2 | 315.0 |
| 314.0 | 354.2 |
| 306.4 | 301.2 |
| 291.7 | 327.8 |
| 333.1 | 332.0 |
| 314.2 | 320.5 |
| 318.0 | 314.6 |
| 301.6 | 321.3 |
| 319.0 | 311.1 |

I'm using Minitab, Two-Sample t for the Mean for this exercise. My question is about what the right interpretation is for the alternative hypothesis. It could be u1-u2 ≠ 0 or u1-u2 < 0 which means u2 (my ball's mean) is greater than u1 (competitor's ball mean).

If u1-u2 ≠ 0 then P value = 0.330 and the answer is option (1).
If u1-u2 < 0, then P value = 0.165 but this does not really fit the options.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put your data into R. Both Welch and pooled 2-sample t tests
gave $T\approx -1,$ and P-value about $0.168 > 5\%$ for a one-sided test
that your cannon balls go farther than your competitor's.
This is in agreement with your first block of Minitab output
and with item (3) in your multiple-choice list.

I think the question is poorly worded, but decipherable, and don't
understand why you did not choose response (3). Please leave a note
if you need further clarification.

---

```
DTA = matrix(c(
341.0,  314.2,
308.2,  315.0,
314.0,  354.2,
306.4,  301.2,
291.7,  327.8,
333.1,  332.0,
314.2,  320.5,
318.0,  314.6,
301.6,  321.3,
319.0,  311.1), byrow=T, ncol=2)

t.test(DTA[,1], DTA[,2], alt="less")

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  DTA[, 1] and DTA[, 2]
t = -1.0017, df = 18, p-value = 0.1649
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is less than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
     -Inf 4.730536
sample estimates:
 mean of x mean of y 
    314.72    321.19
```

Boxplots and stripcharts show variability too large to distinguish
a significant difference in sample locations.

```
boxplot(DTA, col="skyblue2", pch=20, horizontal=T)
```

[image]

```
stripchart(list(DTA[,1], DTA[,2]), pch="|", ylim=c(.5,2.5))
```

[image]

Comment: I also believe the question is poorly worded. My confusion comes because P = 0.168 falls in both ranges of items (1) and (3)

Comment: @Jim (1) _statistical evidence_ vs (3) _no evidence_ . Using a p-value less than 5% to assert "statistical evidence", there is no evidence here, choice (3).

Comment: Understood. Thank you!